# Can't use break in a while-loop

Tags: python

I am having some trouble getting `break` to work in a while-loop.

I have created a function `main()` which contains three `input()` regarding global scopes, these three comes directly after each other. I want the program to end immediately if you enter an incorrect value into one of these `ìnput()` and tried to accomplish that with `break`without success. So the question is why can't I use `break` in my while-loop?

Allowed values in my global scopes:
`Scenario` 1 or 2
`games` should be greater than zero
`board_size` 3, 5 or 7

```
def main():
    
    while True:    
        board_size = int(input("How big playing surface (3/5/7)? "))
        
        if board_size != 3 or board_size != 5 or board_size != 7:
            break
        
    while True:
        games = int(input("How many games do you want to simulate? "))

        if games <1:
            break

    while True:
        scenario = int(input('What scenario (1/2)? '))

        if scenario != 1 or scenario != 2:
            break

    print_stats(games, scenario, board_size)
```

Comment: Surely `if board_size != 3 or board_size != 5 or board_size != 7:` will *always* be true. Since the board has a single size, it will fail to have at least two of those three sizes. Use `if board_size not in [3,5,7]:`

Comment: *"I want the program to end immediately if you enter an incorrect value"* but that's not what `break` does. `break` just ends the current loop, not the whole program.

Comment: If you want the program to end, use `exit()`. If you want the function to terminate, use `return`; also, 'global scope' doesn't mean what you think it does. It's generally a good idea to use plain English when speaking about programming as a beginner, until you have a good understanding of the jargon.

Comment: You should use ```and```, instead ```or```, in the conditional expression! Alternatively, you can write, for example, ```if board_size not in [3,5,7]: break```. Any way, that will stop only the respective loop ```while```, not the function. If you want to stop the execution of the function, use ```return``` instead of ```break```.

Comment: Thank you @kaya3 for the clarification, then I have previously misunderstood the use of break.

Comment: Thank you @Grismar, I will try to use ``return`` instead. English isn't my main language so i thought global scope was the right term to use at this point, but thank you for the clarification! I will read more about global and local scopes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not` logic to check if board_size is equal to 3, 5, or 7. You can use `sys.exit()` to exit the program, but make sure to `import sys`.

```
import sys

def main():
    
    while True:    
        board_size = int(input("How big playing surface (3/5/7)? "))
        
        if not (board_size == 3 or board_size == 5 or board_size == 7):
            sys.exit()
        else:
            break
    while True:
        games = int(input("How many games do you want to simulate? "))

        if games <1:
            sys.exit()
        else:
            break

    while True:
        scenario = int(input('What scenario (1/2)? '))

        if not (scenario == 1 or scenario == 2):
            sys.exit()
        else:
            break

    print(games, scenario, board_size)

main()
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately ``exit()`` didn't work for me, maybe I need to import something to use it? I will read more about ``exit ()``.

Answer (score 2):

Your code will always break as it's never possible for `board_size` to equal `3, 5 or 7`:

Also the programme won't "end" upon breaking a `while True` loop, there are many ways to do this including `sys.exit()`, `raise SystemExit()`, `exit()`...
I think you want:

```
def main():
    
    while True:    
        board_size = int(input("How big playing surface (3/5/7)? "))
        
        if board_size not in [3, 5, 7]:
            raise SystemExit()
        
    while True:
        games = int(input("How many games do you want to simulate? "))

        if games <1:
            raise SystemExit()

    while True:
        scenario = int(input('What scenario (1/2)? '))

        if scenario not in [1, 2]:
            raise SystemExit()

    print_stats(games, scenario, board_size)
```

Comment: Thank you! So I used ``True`` incorrectly after what I was looking for by entering ``if board_size != 3 or board_size != 5 or board_size != 7:``etc?